# Error in IE After Installing Google Adsense Script When Running Locally

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, adsense

I am getting an error in IE after installing Google Adsense Code when running locally. There is no error when I load the project to Azure Web Sites server. Also when I uninstalled JQuery and Bootstrap it still had the same error.

The error is:

Exception was thrown at line 37, column 43 in eval code

0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

All I am doing is:

1) Create new Project in Visual Studio 2013

2) Choose Web Project

3) Choose MVC Template

4) Paste Google Adsense Code into Index.cshtml (home page of site) so that the page looks like (I've removed my account numbers) :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- VTS Basic -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9999932657399999"
     data-ad-slot="9999999999"></ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: It looks like a cross-domain call is forcing some security on you. if it works perfectly in Azure, then it's probably why. What I do is I use the hosts file in my Windows/System32/Drivers/etc file to override my domain to point to my local dev box. That way everything works when I go live and I don't get these security errors. I know it's not a solution you looking for, but it works :)

Comment: Hi user3036342, I think you are right about the cross site security and your solution sounds fine but can you elaborate a bit on what entry I put in the hosts file?

Comment: Sure. In the hosts you will go www.yourdomain.com [press tab] then type in 127.0.0.1 (if your local instance is running on localhost, or enter your virtual machine). It basically forces windows to use that specific IP whenever you type in www.yourdomain.com in the browser. You might have to add yourdomain.com (without the www) too depending which one you use. I do that to test all my wordpress sites locally before deploying live, then I don't have to worry about updating the permalinks etc

Comment: I've decided on a different workaround using Visual Studio. Its not a solution but it is a workaround. When the error message comes up, click "Open Exception Settings", click "Javascript Runtime Exceptions", uncheck the "Thrown" box in "0x80070005 Access Denied".